# Error when integration of Restlet and OSGi

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, osgi, restlet

Today I am trying to integrate Restlet (2.3.4) with OSGi (Equinox Mars) and Jetty 9.3.3 (Reference: https://bryanhunt.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/osgi-at-rest/#comment-439) and I faced with the following exception:

```
Sep 16, 2015 7:08:54 PM org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper getAdapter
SEVERE: Unable to create the HTTP server adapter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.restlet.ext.servlet.internal.ServletServerAdapter
at org.restlet.engine.util.EngineClassLoader.findClass(EngineClassLoader.java:95)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.restlet.engine.Engine.loadClass(Engine.java:356)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.getAdapter(HttpServerHelper.java:102)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:141)
at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1117)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl$LegacyServlet.service(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:1271)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:162)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:63)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.doDispatch(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:413)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.doDispatch(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:365)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.doDispatch(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:204)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:91)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1156)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:306)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:245)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 16, 2015 7:08:54 PM org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper handle
WARNING: Error while handling an HTTP server call
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:141)
at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1117)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl$LegacyServlet.service(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:1271)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:162)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:63)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.doDispatch(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:413)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.doDispatch(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:365)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.doDispatch(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:204)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:91)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1156)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:306)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:245)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After a quick debug I see the Engine is trying to load class “org.restlet.ext.servlet.internal.ServletServerAdapter” but the Engine’s class loader does not see that class… by looking at the source of bundle org.restlet.ext.servlet I did not see any place to register class loader or something like that.. strange to me…

So to make it work I made a dirty modification – I modified org.restlet.jar/MANIFEST.MF and add more import packages: org.restlet.ext.servlet.internal and org.restlet.ext.servlet. It works.

I appreciate if someone helps to resolve this problem in a clean way.. Thank you!